# Making a new array without duplicates in C

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

my code works as far as i can tell..
I was wondering if it can be done in a better way (better time complexity) and what is the time complexity of my code as im not really sure how to caculate it.
cant change the current array in the question but if there is a faster way to do it by removal i would also like to know, thanks a lot.

```
    int i = 1, j = 0, count = 1;
int arrNew[SIZE] = { NULL }; 
arrNew[0] = arr1[0]; 
while(i<size){
    if (arr1[i] == arrNew[j]) { // if the element of arr1 is already added, resets j for next iteration and moves to the next element.
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    else {
        if (j == count - 1) { // checks if we reached the end of arrNew and adds missing element.
            arrNew[count] = arr1[i];
            j = 0;
            count++; // this variable makes sure we check only the assigned elements of arrNew.
            i++;
        }
        else // if j < count -1 we didnt finish checking all of arrNew.
            j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i checked it on 3 unsorted arrays and it worked well..

Comment: Um. pretty sure this will work for non-sorted arrays, but: this will be degenerate to n^2 worst case (array already populated with distinct unique values). For large arrays you're probably better off sorting the original, then single-passing to throw out duplicates. You'll lose the original ordering in doing so, however, which may be a deal breaker for that approach. Depending on the domain, a counting flag-indicator array is also on option, and would be roaring fast if the model fits. Unrelated, a VLA is a recipe for disaster for larger arrays, and probably also needs consideration.

Comment: but i used the count variable to make sure i check only assigned spaces in the array, is it still n^2? SIZE is a variable outside the method(used #define SIZE) because we didnt learn how to make a dynamic array yet..

Comment: Worse case (already distinct unique values), the run will be O(n^2). consider what happens with each pass. every new item as `j` marches up the original will compare against *every* already-classified item in the new array. Since they're all unique already, that means sweeps will be 1, 2, 3, 4... (n-2), (n-1) comparisons. That's a worst case O(n^2) result. Fyi, the best-case, is the entire original filled with the same value. That means an immediate jettison after the first compare on each iteration, resulting in only one final value in the array and a O(n) best-case.

Comment: 1. Your loop is confusingly written, since it increments `i` or `j` conditionally, hiding the loop complexity. 2. if permitted, the sanest approach is to do a "sort into new array" (which is `O(n log n)`), then remove duplicates in a second pass (alternatively, this could be done incrementally using a "partial sort", but this has worse complexity: AFAICT `O((n/m)n log(m))` if done in chunks of size m), 3. if you want to preserve the original order, you could do approach #2 into a temporary buffer, then allocate a bitset and do another pass over the input, doing a binary search and marking it.

Comment: Note that my approach #3 will perform strictly better than using a tree-based set to mark seen elements and output them incrementally, but a hash-based set might do better.

Comment: im not allowed to use any libraries, only loops.. sorting first will still better?

Comment: `qsort` is in the standard library if you can use that. Otherwise, "heapsort" (in-place but not stable) is probably the best in terms of being very easy to understand/implement and having good complexity (unlike "quicksort", which has bad complexity and thus is rarely used to implement `qsort`; "mergesort", which is easy only if you're allowed to allocate extra memory; and other fancy sorting algorithms, which are harder to understand). Note that stability doesn't matter if your values are integers; I've only been mentioning it for completeness.

Comment: ty i think ill try heapsort

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it can be done in a better way (better time complexity)

It's a little hard to tell what's going on at first, but it looks like you're basically using one loop to do two jobs. You're looping on `i` to step through the original array, but also using `j` to scan through the new array for each new element. Effectively, you've got nested loops that both potentially have the same size, so you've got O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

I'd suggest rewriting your code so that the two loops are explicit. You're not saving any time by making one loop do double duty, and if you come back to this code a month from now you're going to waste a bunch of time trying to remember how it works. Make your code *obvious* — it's as much about communicating with your future self or your coworkers as with the compiler.

Can you improve on that O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity? **Yes, definitely.** One way is to sort the array, so that duplicate values end up being adjacent to each other in the array. It's then easy to just not copy any values that are the same as the preceding value. I know you can't modify the original array, but you can copy the whole thing, sort it, and then copy that array while removing dupes. That'd give you O(n log n) complexity (if you choose an efficient sorting algorithm). In fact, you could speed that up a bit by combining the sorting and copying -- but you'd still end up with O(n log n) complexity. Another way is to use a hash table: check to see whether the value exists in the table, tossing it if it does, or adding it to the table and copying to the new array if it doesn't. That'd be close to O(n).

Comment: Remember that a combined `sort_and_copy` implementation is usually more efficient than a separate `copy` and `sort_in_place` - especially if stability is desired. Regretfully, the C standard library only offers in-place non-stable sorting. but fortunately, most people know to use third-party libraries for everything.

Comment: the sorting is nlogn, isnt it? afterwards ill still need to go through the array to remove the duplicates.. wont it take more time unless i have very few duplicates in the array?

Comment: Most general-purpose in-place stable sorting algorithms are `O(n log² n)` or worse, actually (supposedly "block merge sort" is an exception, but I've never heard of it before looking it up just now - and even it suggests that extra memory would be preferred, since otherwise it has fewer "best case"s). If you drop either the "stable" or "in-place" requirement, or can place harsh restrictions on your input, many more algorithms are known.

Comment: Removing duplicates in-place is just `O(n)`, which disappears next to the complexity of sorting. Simply iterate once over the array with two indexes: increment "source" unconditionally but "dest" only if you actually found a new value. Then do a `realloc` to shrink it at the end.

Comment: @technical The idea I described is: copy the array, sort that in place, and then copy that while removing duplicates. So you're copying the array twice (both O(n)) and sorting it once (O(n log n)), so the overall complexity is O(n log n). When we talk about big-O complexity, we're really interested in how the performance changes with the size of the problem.

Comment: @o11c Stability (meaning that it preserves the relative ordering of equivalent keys) doesn't seem important here since we're eliminating equivalent keys anyway. Heapsort and mergesort are both widely described as O(n log n).

Comment: @Caleb stability *can* matter when removing duplicates: "only keep first match" vs "keep one arbitrary match". The actual reason it doesn't matter here is because the key is the entire value (which is usually the case for just integers). But regardless of that, "merge sort" is only `O(n log n)` if you are allowed `O(n)` extra space (and since we're unable to modify the input array, I don't see a way for that to count).

Comment: @o11c No doubt that it *can* matter, but I think we agree that it doesn't in this case. The only restriction I see in the OP's statement of the problem is not changing the original, but as far as I understand we're free to copy the array and do whatever we like to the copy. And honestly, I wouldn't get too caught up in the sorting business when there are even faster methods anyway. My main point here is to answer affirmatively the OP's question about whether better approaches exist, and to demonstrate that *yes* with some possibilities. Let's leave the actual implementation as an exercise. ;-)